# How to change brackets for array used with JavaScript's JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using `JSON.stringify` to put an array into the search part of the URL. By default JSON uses square brackets, `[]` for arrays.

However, square brackets in URLs sometimes lead to strange problems. For example when sending a URL with square brackets in an email with Thunderbird the hyperlink gets cut off just before the first occurrence of a square bracket.

Is it possible to make JSON use another style of brackets? E.g. normal brackets, `()`?

Comment: What you have there is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/169187). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, both `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` leave square brackets untouched (tested in Firefox).

Comment: It still seems you are not encoding your data properly or don't process it correctly on the server. Square brackets work usually very well in URLs.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I forgot adding that the problem with sending of the URL is in a Thunderbird mail. No problem in my browser with square brackets. I just want to make it save for other programs, like Thunderbird, as well.

Comment: You can't tell JSON to use another type of brackets, because then *it's not JSON*. You can, however, replace the square brackets yourself after generating the string - more than enough information on how to do that available already. Just make sure to do the opposite before you try to parse the string as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Not sure where this kind of information is available, e.g. an easy `.replace(/\[/g, "(").replace(/\]/g, ")")` will not do, since there may be square brackets in the values of the array which are lost when decoding again with `.replace`. That's why I was wondering whether there is a specific (related) JSON function for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JSON doesnt offer this functionality, what you would have to do is replace the [] with something unique before you transfer your data, then replace them back on the server, but realistically its a bad idea to pass json in a url via get

Comment: Thanks, I may try to work around it as you suggested. Not sure why it is in general a bad idea to pass JSON in a URL. What would be the alternative? Passing in a URL has some nice benefits, like save data via bookmarking.